# Users not going offline

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

So basically I have this script for my server that keeps all the users up to date on my panel for my .net licensing system, but for some reason some of the users don't go offline when they are most definitely not connected to the server.

Basically every time the user checks in( every minute ) it will update their account with the time they checked in. Then I have the following script to check if the user's check in time is 2 minutes behind the time it is now, so then it will set them offline as they haven't checked in, in 2 minutes.

My problem is, it is working for most users, but like 9% of them don't go offline when checking and there seems to be no errors, unless i'm wrong, can anyone help me out in fixing this simple problem?

**PHP SCRIPT:**

```
$SQLGetUsers = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM Account");
while ($getInfo = $SQLGetUsers -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $getInfo['id'];
    $lastlogon = $getInfo['lastlogon'];
    $time = time();
    $timeouttime = ($time - 120);
    if ($lastlogon <= $timeouttime) 
    {
        $odb->exec("UPDATE Account SET `online` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    }
    $odb->exec("OPTIMIZE TABLE Account");
}
```

I do know this is a bad script, but it's the only way I personally know of executing this specific command. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: How are you running this script?

Comment: You don't need a loop, just a single query: `UPDATE Account SET online WHERE lastlogon < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE))`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute` . In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for advice on how to avoid problem like this.

Comment: @Barmar I am running this script with cronjobs.

Comment: @tadman While I agree with that statement, the used data in `exec()` is from the database so it can be trusted, especially `id` and and I suspect `lastlogon` is not user generated data as well. Using `prepare()` in this specific scenario is just inefficient.

Comment: @Xorifelse You get in the habit of "trusting" data and then you get burned. It's not worth the risk. Use placeholder values. Do not interpolate. People have tools that test for sloppy coding like this and they can crack your site wide open with a single tiny mistake.

Comment: You are running `OPTIMIZE TABLE Account` inside your loop!? Maybe this needs so long that your script runs into a timeout. Also please read Barmars suggested code. And read it again. And then again. Then use it.

Comment: @Barmar - (typo)   `... SET online = 1 WHERE ...`

Comment: @Xorifelse - The "inefficiency" of `prepare` is insignificant compared to the cost of fetching even one row from the database.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is essentially _never_ needed, especially with InnoDB.  (Speaking of inefficiency!!)